# What's the difference between "Hack" and "Hack No Key" options?

Tags: ingress

When I am in range of a portal and when I click and hold, it displays 4 options.

1. Hack
2. Hack No Key
3. Fire XMP
4. Deploy

So whats the main difference between "Hack"ing a portal and "Hack No Key"ing a portal?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hack no key, as the name suggests, will give you no key. You can also achieve this via glyph hacking and signaling 'less' via the control channel, but this is a lot more convenient.

It is quite useful while farming for items, or travelling in a new area you know you need no keys from, but it's good for your explorer badge. Spares you getting rid of the keys later.

Comment: Look, i am new to ingress. So i want to ask why would somebody want to get rid of the keys later?

Comment: Because your inventory is full and you don't need them. That being said, currently portals spew no XM, thus hacking for the key and then recycling them makes more sense than using "hack no key".

Comment: You can also swipe the glyph for 'more' and request a key even if you already have one. Having duplicate keys of portals you want to link to can be useful.

Comment: Additionally, if you hold down on 'hack' or 'hack no key' for a few seconds, you get a minigame showing you a series of glyphs to swipe in order. Get them all right and you get bonus AP and items.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you can enter glyph hacking like this, I always opened the portail details screen first and long-pressed there, thanks!

Comment: @Shadur you can't do that. The glyph screen is only accessible from the portal screen, not from the long-press-menu.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs I've been out of the loop for about a year. Why are portals not dropping xm? Is shit about to hit the fan again?

Comment: @Carcigenicate That question is seriously off-topic, easily answerable with a net search, and I don't follow the Ingress storyline anyway.